# Form with Multiple Steps

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I made a registration form which there are 4 steps, but it has a bug that is when the user clicks the payment button (the last step) it will go to a new tab which is the payment gateway, and when the user clicks on the registration form tab, the form only shows the previous button and the payment button only, and the button is not working, help me fix the bug

registration form after click payment button

[image]

```js
function calculateOrEnterAge(person) {
  var noKadPengenalan = document.getElementById("no_kad_pengenalan_" + person).value;
  var umurInput = document.getElementById("umur_" + person);

  // Check if the input is a number and not empty
  if (!isNaN(noKadPengenalan) && noKadPengenalan !== "") {
    var firstTwoDigits = noKadPengenalan.substring(0, 2);
    var birthYear;

    if (firstTwoDigits >= "00" && firstTwoDigits <= "05") {
      birthYear = "20" + firstTwoDigits;
    } else if (firstTwoDigits >= "06" && firstTwoDigits <= "99") {
      birthYear = "19" + firstTwoDigits;
    }

    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var umur = currentYear - parseInt(birthYear);
    umurInput.value = umur;
  } else {
    // If input is not a number or empty, clear the age value
    umurInput.value = "";
  }
}

var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Click To Pay";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n);
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Add Bootstrap CSS Link -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- font awesome cdn link  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<!-- lightgallery css cdn link -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery-js/1.4.0/css/lightgallery.min.css">
<!-- custom css file link  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="student-style.css">

<a href="index.php" class="back-button">
  <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
</a>

<form id="regForm" action="process-registration.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <h2 class="mt-0">Register:</h2>
  <div class="tab">
    <h4>Step 1: Maklumat Pelajar</h4>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="servis">Servis:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="servis" name="servis">
            <option value="tadika">Tadika</option>
            <option value="transit">Transit</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tarikh">Tarikh Daftar:</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tarikh" name="tarikh" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nama:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div><br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="gender" class="mr-3">Jantina:</label>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">

        <input type="radio" id="perempuan" name="gender" value="Perempuan" oninput="this.className = ''" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="perempuan">Perempuan</label>
        <input type="radio" id="lelaki" name="gender" value="Lelaki" oninput="this.className = ''" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="lelaki">Lelaki</label>
      </div>
    </div><br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="no_surat_beranak">No. Surat Beranak:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="no_surat_beranak" name="no_surat_beranak" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tarikh_lahir">Tarikh Lahir:</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tarikh_lahir" name="tarikh_lahir" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="anak_ke">Anak ke Berapa:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="anak_ke" name="anak_ke" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="alamat_rumah">Alamat:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="alamat_rumah" name="alamat_rumah" rows="4" placeholder="Alamat"></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <h4>Step 2: Maklumat Ibubapa/Penjaga</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nama_bapa_penjaga">Nama Bapa/Penjaga:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_bapa_penjaga" name="nama_bapa_penjaga" required>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="no_kad_pengenalan_bapa">No. Kad Pengenalan:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="no_kad_pengenalan_bapa" name="no_kad_pengenalan_bapa" required oninput="calculateOrEnterAge('bapa')">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="warna_bapa">Warna:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="warna_bapa" name="warna_bapa">
            <option value="Biru Muda">Biru Muda</option>
            <option value="Merah Muda">Merah Muda</option>
            <option value="Hijau Muda">Hijau Muda</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="umur_bapa">Umur:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="umur_bapa" name="umur_bapa" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="no_tel_rumah_bimbit_bapa">No. Tel Rumah/Bimbit:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no_tel_rumah_bimbit_bapa" name="no_tel_rumah_bimbit_bapa">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bangsa_bapa">Bangsa:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bangsa_bapa" name="bangsa_bapa">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="warganegara_bapa">Warganegara:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="warganegara_bapa" name="warganegara_bapa">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pekerjaan_bapa">Pekerjaan:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pekerjaan_bapa" name="pekerjaan_bapa">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="majikan_bapa">Majikan:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="majikan_bapa" name="majikan_bapa">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="no_tel_pejabat_bapa">No. Tel Pejabat:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no_tel_pejabat_bapa" name="no_tel_pejabat_bapa">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nama_ibu_penjaga">Nama Ibu/Penjaga:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_ibu_penjaga" name="nama_ibu_penjaga" required>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="no_kad_pengenalan_ibu">No. Kad Pengenalan:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="no_kad_pengenalan_ibu" name="no_kad_pengenalan_ibu" required oninput="calculateOrEnterAge('ibu')">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="warna_ibu">Warna:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="warna_ibu" name="warna_ibu">
            <option value="Biru Muda">Biru Muda</option>
            <option value="Merah Muda">Merah Muda</option>
            <option value="Hijau Muda">Hijau Muda</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="umur_ibu">Umur:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="umur_ibu" name="umur_ibu" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="no_tel_rumah_bimbit_ibu">No. Tel Rumah/Bimbit:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no_tel_rumah_bimbit_ibu" name="no_tel_rumah_bimbit_ibu">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bangsa_ibu">Bangsa:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bangsa_ibu" name="bangsa_ibu">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="warganegara_ibu">Warganegara:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="warganegara_ibu" name="warganegara_ibu">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pekerjaan_ibu">Pekerjaan:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pekerjaan_ibu" name="pekerjaan_ibu">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="majikan_ibu">Majikan:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="majikan_ibu" name="majikan_ibu">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="no_tel_pejabat_ibu">No. Tel Pejabat:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no_tel_pejabat_ibu" name="no_tel_pejabat_ibu">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <h4>Step 3: Maklumat Kesihatan Anak-anak</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="penyakit">Adakah anak anda mempunyai penyakit? Sila nyatakan jika ada:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="penyakit" name="penyakit">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="alahan_makanan">Adakah anak anda mempunyai alahan terhadap makanan? Sila nyatakan jika ada:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alahan_makanan" name="alahan_makanan">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="kecemasan_nama">Sekiranya berlaku kecemasan, siapakah yang harus dihubungi selain
                    ibubapa/pejaga:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kecemasan_nama" name="kecemasan_nama" placeholder="Nama">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="kecemasan_tel">No. Tel Rumah/Bimbit:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kecemasan_tel" name="kecemasan_tel" placeholder="No. Tel Rumah/Bimbit">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="kecemasan_petalian">Petalian dengan murid:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kecemasan_petalian" name="kecemasan_petalian" placeholder="Petalian dengan murid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="kecemasan_alamat">Alamat:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="kecemasan_alamat" name="kecemasan_alamat" rows="4" placeholder="Alamat"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <h2>Step 4: Transaction Details</h2>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="transaction_method">Payment Method:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="transaction_method" name="transaction_method">
        <option value="bank_transfer">Bank Transfer</option>
        <option value="paypal">ToyyidPay</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="payer_name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payer_name" name="payer_name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="payer_no_phone">No. Phone:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payer_no_phone" name="payer_no_phone">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="payer_email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payer_email" name="payer_email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="price">Harga:</label>
      <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="RM101">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" class="btn btn-secondary">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Add Bootstrap JS and Popper.js Scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and make it a [mcve] - for example by adding relevant CSS